# Face recognize API for .net-mvc4

Tags: c#, image-recognition

I need to build application with face recognition. The user of application need to upload two pictures(two faces) and application need to return the percentage of similarity of this faces.
I looking for API that do this job as well. 
Today i worked with SkyBiometry.Client.FC, this API have two algorithms of recognizing : Default(simple) and Aggressive(more aggressive compare). In all cases of various pictures compare i get result of 60% - 68%. This is not good :). 
What API (tested) do you recommend to use for this purpose?

Comment: Retagged to help you out a little, specifying MVC versions is irrelevant to this question in my opinion.

Comment: Can you provide some more details - what kind of training set did you use (number of pics per user)? Have you looked at the lighting? The problem could be with either of these too.

Comment: Hi KingCronus, my mistake it was really not relevant to specifying MVC versions

Comment: Hi Srikanth Venugopalan and thanks for reply, like i said, i need to compare 2 photos similarity. For example picture of son and father and return a percentage of their similarity

Comment: Normal and Aggressive are settings for face detector. This setting shall not have impact on recognition results (assuming the same face is detected in the same picture for both detector settings).
As for the recognition score please see the answer to another question of yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14478658/handle-skybiometry-api/14481783.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question but Microsoft has a couple of APIs for face detection.

Face API : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt481457.aspx

API Reference : https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395236

Starting tutorial : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt605323.aspx

They're very simple to understand and use. I've tried them and they work pretty well.

Hope this helps someone re-visiting this question.!