# how to use SkyBiometry in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, face-detection

I recently started a new project that needs to face detection and tagging. After a lot of search on google, I found that the best way is using [skybiometry.com](https://skybiometry.com) free module. But it's really really weird that there isn't any documentation to use skybiometry in asp.net.
however, I finally could get its library from [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SkyBiometry.Client.FC) and get small things from [Handle SkyBiometry API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14478658/handle-skybiometry-apisomethings).
Anyone knows how we can use skybiometry in asp.net using C#?

Comment: Have you tried downloading the demo client? https://skybiometry.com/document/libraries/

Comment: Yes, I was it, There isn't any interesting documentation.

Comment: I guess trial and error is the way forward then.